# How to scroll a div which is loaded inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm loading a page(A) inside an iframe. Html of page(A) is like this:

```
<html><body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"><button>Hello</button></div>
</body></html>
```

The iframe is loaded like this:

```
<html><body>
<iframe src="pageA.html" height="200px"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Here, `div2` stays at the bottom of the page and `div1` is fixed height with `overflow:scroll`. When the `button` is pressed, some content will be appended to `div1`.

What I need to do is scroll down the `div1` to bottom so that the newly added content is visible in the iframe. How can I do this?

Edit:
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqLYD/) of what I've tried.
This works when HTML is loaded in browser but does not work when loaded in a fixed height iframe.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle for what you already tried?

Comment: [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView)?

Comment: @merlin Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqLYD/) This works when loading in a browser but does not work when loaded inside fixed height iframe.

Comment: @Teemu seems it works! Thanks a lot. Would you please post it as answer so that I can accept?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zD7Xr/) Works in chrome.

Comment: @merlin yes, it works in chrome. Does it work when the html is loaded inside an iframe?

Comment: @Rafiqunnabi See the fiddle above, it's loaded inside an iframe.

Comment: @merlin wow! Thanks a lot, it's working in JSFiddle. But still not working in my code. Let me double check it. Thanks again! Would you please post your JSFiddle as an answer?

Comment: @Rafiqunnabi no prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newly added content is at the bottom. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zD7Xr/).

```
<iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/DqLYD/show/" height="200px"></iframe>
```